# How to model torque and linear force of collisions for a simple 2D physics engine

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, torque

I'm attempting to make a simple physics engine but chat gpt for the most part has been unreliable.

I have a **2d space** (vacumm).

For simplicity I would like to model collisions between extended circular objects that take changes in angular and linear velocity (and kinetic energy) into account. I would like help with physics principles and equations that are involved to accurately calculate these 2D collisions in my simple physics engine simulation.

Comment: Also if your able to, answer with c++ code. To help the object is a class with variables; position, center of mass, mass, linear velocity, angular velocity. Point: position, force

Comment: This might be a case where ChatGPT isn't quite as useful as a teaching site or youtube tutorials.  Building an engine requires not just understanding individual cases like this, but understanding the physics.  Engines get put into all sorts of weird situations that they have to shovel their way out of.  From experience, any time you spend on understanding the basic physics of forces, torques, and impulses will pay for itself by reducing the amount of time you spend debugging the engine afterwards.  Never underestimate the cost of debugging.

Comment: I already had most of the physics engine (object) but I had issues with figuring how force exterted for momentum transfer results in torque and I almost got the answer but in the process I converted angular momentum into linear momentum to help with the conversion and found it near impossible to neatly convert back so I came up with this to find a solution online (and to simplify my physics with a new way to handle force) @CortAmmon

Comment: Why do you need ChatGPT when the equations of motion of particles have been known for 400 years now? $$\vec{F} = m \vec{a}$$ Of course the difficulty is always with doing the kinematics and finding out what $\vec{a}$ is based on the _degrees of freedom_ that **you** decide.

Comment: In general in dynamics, the positions and velocities _after some time_ are not known analytically, but come out of a simulation process. The simulation process job and maybe the part you are stuck is to find the acceleration as a function of position and velocity (if applicable) and feeding that into an ODE solver to advance time.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou because when force is exerted on a specific point offcenter on the object some of the object would lag behind resulting in rotation and that is what im asking about. I know the force to start with but not the resulting linear and angular velocities. I don't understand rotation dynamics in physics.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou I'm not looking for position after time and the force is given on the immediate first instance not constantly overtime.

Comment: https://www.toptal.com/game/video-game-physics-part-i-an-introduction-to-rigid-body-dynamics

Comment: You can sleep with your doubt but never search your physics doubt on ChatGPT, last night i was very desperate to solve my doubt and it was kind of a conceptual flaw related to polar coordinates. I searched on ChatGPT, now i am in more doubt

Comment: @JohnAlexiou This link looks promising thanks for your input.

Comment: Your doubt seems to be related to steps (4) and (5) in my answer below. Is this a fair assessment?

Comment: A word about chatGPT. Sometimes for fun I ask chat GPT a simple physics or mathematics question and in my experience chatGPT get the answer wrong >99% of the time. chat GPT is great at making up stories, drawing pictures, looking up historical facts, but for physics and mathematics question it has the IQ of 4 year old.  Now I don't know if this is just a limitation of AI at the moment or if chatGPT is deliberately "hobbled" so that it cannot be used for cheating at homework in maths and physics. If you must use chatGPT, challenge everything it tells you. It is nearly always wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified enough information to solve the problem.

Finding the final velocity is simpler.  If a constant force is applied over a **time** $\Delta t$, then the final velocity $\vec{v}_f$ of the object will be related to its initial velocity by
$$
\vec{v}_f - \vec{v}_i = \frac{\vec{F}}{m} \Delta t.
$$
In your case, the object is starting from rest, so $\vec{v}_i = 0$.  So if you know the amount of time over which the force is being applied (and assuming that the force doesn't change magnitude or direction during that time), you can find $\vec{v}_f$.

The angular velocity is trickier.  For 2-D rotations the initial & final angular velocities ($\omega_i$ & $\omega_f$ respectively) are
$$
\omega_f - \omega_i = \frac{\tau}{I} \Delta t
$$
where $\tau$ is the **torque** exerted and $I$ is the **moment of inertia** of the object.  The torque is easy enough to calculate:
$$
\tau = |\vec{F} \times \vec{r} | = F_x y - F_y x
$$
where $\vec{r}$ here is the position of the application of the force ((-1,0) in your case).  But you will also need to know the moment of inertia of the object, which depends on the size and shape of the object.

Finally, a few notes & nitpicks:

- There's no way to guarantee that the results for the final linear velocity and angular velocity have magnitudes between 0 and 1.  The final results are what they are.
- The units of force are $\text{kg} \cdot \text{m/s}^2$, not $\text{kg} \cdot \text{m/s}$.

Comment: I'm sure the variables would have a magnitude of greater than 0 and less than one because I provided 1 newton of force. If magnitude were greater than 1 it would break the second law of thermodynamics by adding extra force than I provided for the scenario. And zero or less would result in loss of all force or impossible impossible measurement of force. I don't know the answer to my problem but I do have conditions to tell if an answer is false. Also force = mass (kg) * acceleration (meters), Im not applying 1 meter in both x and y direction only the y direction so it is kg * m/s.

Comment: I ran out of room on my reply... Also for moment of inertia all i need to know is the the center of mass and the mass of the object which I have provided, did I do something wrong?

Comment: Also the force is not constant it is for the initial instance only I would add some of your suggestions in my original question.

Comment: Unfortunately the moment of inertia absolutely depends on the shape of the object, and has to be calculated with a double integral in 2D. Here are some examples at wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia and acceleration is $kgms^{-2}$ Vector direction doesn't make any difference. Finally to calculate final velocity  you need to specify how long the force acts (t). If the force acts only momentarily, then you need to specify the distance it acts, as the work done to accelerate the object is F*d. A force does no work if it does not move.

Comment: The center of mass is also dependent on the shape. And for the sake of simplicity the object always rotates around that point. Which is why I presume I don't need to know the geometry of the object. But If not I could add an exception to treat every object like a circle. The engine does not need to be perfectly accurate to the real world.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I slightly altered the prompt if this could help find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

When doing dynamics on a rigid body, you need to sum up the net forces acting on the body $\vec{F}_{\rm net}$ and the net (equipollent) torque about the center of mass of the body $\vec{\tau}_{\rm net}$.

$$ \vec{F}_{\rm net} = \sum_i \vec{F}_i \tag{1}$$
$$ \vec{\tau}_{\rm net} = \sum_i \vec{r}_i \times \vec{F}_i \tag{2}$$

where $\vec{r}_i$ is the point of application of force $\vec{F}_i$ relative to the center of mass.

You also need to decide on what variables to use to track the position and velocity of the body, both translational and rotational. These are called the degrees of freedom, and they are a function of time. Typically positional/angle variables are designated $q_i$ and velocity/rotation variables are ther derivatives $\dot{q}_i$.

Using the chain rule of calculus you track the center of mass and orientation of the body to get the translational and rotational acceleration of the center of mass and body:

$$ \vec{a} = f(t,q_1,q_2,\ldots,\dot{q}_1,\dot{q}_2,\ldots) \tag{3} $$
$$ \vec{\alpha} = g(t,q_1,q_2,\ldots,\dot{q}_1,\dot{q}_2,\ldots) \tag{4} $$

Finally, apply the equations of motion

$$ \vec{F}_{\rm net} = m \vec{a} \tag{5}$$

$$ \vec{\tau}_{\rm net} = {\rm I}\, \vec{\alpha} + \vec{\omega} \times ( {\rm I}\, \vec{\omega}) \tag{6}$$

Here ${\rm I}$ is the mass moment of inertia tensor for the body, and I am not going to go into detail into describing it. Any course in 3D dynamics in college will cover these topics extensively. There are also a lot of free online sources for this.